# How to select individual values from non-contiguous named range in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've created some named ranges on a spreadsheet which are built up from non-contiguous cells.

For example I've created one called report:

```
=Report!$M2,Report!$Y2,Report!$AK2
```

I can select the first element of the named array with the following formula:

```
=index(report, 1)
```

But how do I select the second and third elements?

I tried:

```
=index(report, 2)
```

But it failed. What have I failed to grasp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access that **area** using the optional area_num parameter of the `INDEX` function. It's the fourth parameter. E.g.

```
=INDEX(report,,,2)
```

If that area contains more than one cell you can access the second element (for example) like this:

```
=INDEX(report,2,,2)
```

Comment: That's great. Thank you.

Comment: @elksie5000, if you found that answered your question please mark it as the accepted answer (it's the tick mark on the left)

Comment: @CallumDA Under what circumstances do you need to nest the `INDEX` functions?  If I want to return the 2nd cell from the 2nd area in a 3-column discontiguous range, merely use:  `=INDEX(DiscontigRange,2,1,2)` where `DiscontigRange   Refers To:   =Sheet1!$A$1:$A$3,Sheet1!$D$1:$D$3,Sheet1!$F$1:$F$3`

Comment: Brilliant! I don't know why I haven't come across that before! I'll update - thanks :)